# C# Excel - How to switch to existing Worksheet and edit it?

Tags: c#, excel

So I open an existing Excel Application with a few Worksheets and add one Worksheet and edit it. That works perfectly fine.

Now I try to switch to another Worksheet to edit this one. Code here:

```
Excel.Worksheet OptimaPruefliste = OptimaWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
OptimaPruefliste.Activate();

try
{
    OptimaPruefliste.Range["A1:ZZ9999"].Borders.LineStyle = true;
    OptimaPruefliste.Range["A1:ZZ9999"].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

It doesn´t throw an exception and it does get "OptimaPruefliste" as active sheet but it just doesn´t change anything.

Comment: Your code worked for me just fine. So there must _something else_. This code should work.

Comment: Somehow it did not for me. But I figured out a way that worked. I post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So these three lines did the job:

```
OptimaPruefliste = (Worksheet)OptimaExcelApp.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
OptimaPruefliste.Activate();
OptimaPruefliste = OptimaExcelApp.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
```